# ADF Copy Activity problem with wildcard path

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, wildcard-mapping

I have a seemingly simple task to integrate multiple json files that are residing in a data lake gen2
The problem is files that need to be integrated are located in multiple folders, for example this is a typical structure that I am dealing with:
Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\2022\Month\Day\Hour\Minute\ <---1 file in Minute Folder
Than same structure for 20223 year, so in order for me to collect all the files I have to go to bottom of the structure which is Minute folder, if I use wildcard path it looks like this:
Wildcard paths 'source from dataset"/ *.json, it copies everything including all folders, and I just want files, I tried to narrow it down and copies only first for 2022 but whatever I do is not working  in terms of wildcard paths, help is much appreciated

trying different wildcard combinations did not help, obviously I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to copy files from multiple sub- folders to single destination folder. Flatten hierarchy as a copy behavior also will have autogenerated file names in target.

[image]
**image reference** [MS document on copy behaviour](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system?tabs=data-factory#file-system-as-sink)

Instead, you can follow the below approach.

- In order to list the file path in the container, take the **Lookup activity** and connect to xml dataset with HTTP linked service.

Give the **Base URL in HTTP connector** as,
`https://<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>?restype=directory&comp=list`.

[Replace `<storage account name>` and `<container>` with the appropriate name in the above URL]

[image]

- Lookup activity gives the list of folders and files as separate line items as in following image.

[image]

- Take the **Filter activity** and filter the URLs that end with `.json`  from the lookup activity output.

Settings of filter activity:

**items:**
`@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].EnumerationResults.Blobs.Blob`

**condition:**
`@endswith(item().URL,'.json')`

**Output of filter activity**
[image]

- Take the for-each activity next to filter activity and give the item of for-each as  `@activity('Filter1').output.value`
- Inside for-each activity, take the copy activity.
- Take http connector and json dataset as source, give the base url as
  `https://<account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/`
- Create the parameter for relative URL and value for that parameter as `@item().name`

[image]

- In sink, give the container name and folder name.
- Give the file name as dynamic content.
  `@split(item().name,'/')[sub(length(split(item().name,'/')),1)]`

This expression will take the filename from relative URL value.
[image]

- When the pipeline is run, all files from multiple folders got copied to single folder.
  [image]